# Why is a TV station scrambling dirty words when it created the series themselves?

Tags: dialogue, the-magicians

I am watching [*The Magicians*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Magicians_(American_TV_series)) and noticed that "fucking" (or other variations of "fuck" - I did not notice that with other words) is **scrambled** to "fng" (more or less). The viewer is expected to recognize the dirty word.

Why would Syfy do that? They created the series so they could have gone with "freaking" or something like that instead of a bleeping if they wanted to go for a younger rating.

I do not even think that the rating is the reason - extracted eyeballs or other violent elements would surely require a higher rating. This is not sure, though, as nudity or profanity is usually more problematic in the US than violence (I do not have sources for that).

Comment: @Raj: thank you - I self-marked it as an exact duplicate

Comment: I don't know, but it seems possible that two versions of the series were created, one with more profanity etc. to have a harder rating and one with the profanity scrambled a bit to have a lower rating.  That way they could have a version for markets desiring harsher language and a version for markets desiring cleaner language.  Or possibly they decided after it was produced to dub some words for a younger rating.  A lot of scenes are often dubbed in post production for better sound clarity anyway, so scrambling some dirty words would be no big deal.